# HTML 5 geolocation on Android only works if high accuracy is requested

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to use geolocation on my Android phone (Nexus 5) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Geolocation test</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result">Getting location...</div>

        <script>
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succ, err, {
                timeout: 10000
            });

            function succ(pos) {
                $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(pos.coords));
            }

            function err(err) {
                $('#result').html('Error: ' + err.message);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, it always throws the timeout error after 10 seconds. If I add `enableHighAccuracy: true` it uses the GPS and works fine, but I'd like to get the network location because it's faster and accurate enough for my purposes.

Any ideas for why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my phone solved the problem, strange.